# Express delete-route not working with angular applications

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, postman

Somehow Delete (and put/patch) routes never work. they work fine when testing with postman but never when called from my angular applications.

```
//calling delete route from angular application. this does not work
DeleteDay(){
    this.http.delete("http://192.168.1.102:3000/api/5f7a391013cbd02ea001fb82");
}


//delete route from server
router.delete('/:postId', async (req, res) => {
try{
    const removedPost = await Dag.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: req.params.postId });
    res.json(removedPost);
} catch(err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
}
});
```

//calling delete using postman. this DOES work
[screen from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSnb.png)

Comment: when i call the delete-route using python if works fine.

Comment: And what does your browser console/network tab say? Because I bet you forgot to implement the `options` handler. Browsers, unlike curl, postman, python, or any other not-browser, send an OPTIONS request first, to see which verb is even allowed. (This is called the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)) and if there is no response, they won't even send the POST/PUT/DELETE request.

Comment: You probably need to return CORS-headers (if you are using express see http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `HttpClient` makes HTTP requests, it returns an [Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) which needs to be subscribed. The same may work on postman but while using it in angular, you need to subscribe to it in the following way:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
//your function
DeleteDay(id:string){
console.log("id could be made dynamic",id);//5f7a391013cbd02ea001fb82
this.http.delete("http://192.168.1.102:3000/api/"+id) 
    .subscribe((data)=>{ 
      console.log(data); //data will actually be an Object sent from Express
    })
}
```

PS: I have changed your function to work even on dynamic IDs, use it as per your need.

Comment: This solved my problem. I thought subscribing was optional.